# What is the Residue of a complex function at a point?

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been dipping my toe into the waters of complex analysis and have begun to learn what the residue of a point of a complex function is.

For some complex function $f$, and some point $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$, the residue of $f(z_0)$ is defined by the coefficient of the negative first power in the Laurent series expansion of $f$.

This is all fine an dandy, but my question is why is the negative first power of such significance, what about the negative second or third powers. As a newbie looking in, there doesn't seem to be anything particularly important about this term in the series, so why does it carry so much weight in complex analysis?

Any tips or suggested readings would be appreciated!!

Comment: For one thing, the [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) allows us to integrate more easily.

Comment: The residue is the integral of the function along an arbitrarily small circle centered at the point. The equivalence to that coefficient is a consequence in the case that the function has such a representation as a Laurent series.

Comment: The reason why that term becomes relevant is because the integral of $z^n$ along a circle centered at the origin is zero, except for the case $n=-1$. Therefore, when you have a Laurent series and exchange the order of integration and summation the integrals of all terms are zero except for the term of degree $-1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because it's the obstacle that prevents $f$ from having a primitive near $z_0$. Indeed, if$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}a_n(z-z_0)^n,$$then $f$ has a primitive $F$ in the neighborhood of $z_0$ if and only if $a_{-1}=0$. If $a_{-1}=0$, then that primitive will be, of course$$F(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-2}\frac{a_n}{n+1}(z-z_0)^{n+1}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a_n}{n+1}(z-z_0)^{n+1}.$$